# React Native With Loadash Module Not Found

Tags: react-native, node-modules

I am unable to import loadash to react native app.

Steps Followed:

1- NPM Install
   npm install loadash --save

2- Import
   import _ from 'loadash'
   Tried importing like this also : let _ = require('loadash');

3- Usage
   _.isUndefined(Key);

Package.json

```
"dependencies": {
"lodash": "^4.17.5",
"react": "16.2.0",
"react-native": "0.53.3"
```

}

Any Solution will be welcome, I tried removed node_modules and installing again also I tried these below steps:

- Clear watchman watches: `watchman watch-del-all`.
- Delete the `node_modules` folder: `rm -rf node_modules && npm
  install`.
- Reset Metro Bundler cache: `rm -rf $TMPDIR/react-*` or `npm start -- 
  --reset-cache`.
- Remove haste cache: `rm -rf
  $TMPDIR/haste-map-react-native-packager-*`.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a typo, it's `lodash`, not `loadash`

Comment: Oh Thanks, That was a my bad.